# Passing function to specific DOM element

Tags: jquery, dom, this

My question is: how do I pass a specific jQuery plugin function to a DOM element and not all the elements? I think there are two things wrong in the code I am using and the plugin I am using.

I am using a fileupload plugin that starts out like this:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.AjaxImgUpload = function() {
        // Variable to store your files
        var files;
        alert ($(this));
        // Add events
        $(this, 'input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

        $(this, 'form').on('submit', uploadFiles);
};
})(jQuery);
```

Note that it was me who added the jquery plugin extension method. The plugin was originally just a script. Anyway I attach the function to a form element like this:

```
$("#leagueLogoUpload").AjaxImgUpload({});
```

While this works, because of the function events, it makes all form objects in the DOM run the uploadFiles function. I know I must be doing something wrong. My logic was to isolate the #leagueLogoUpload form but I don't think I'm doing it right. I thought that $this would mean $this DOM element and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Within a custom jQuery function, `this` refers to the jQuery result set (an array of elements), so you need to use `this.find()`:

```
this.find('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

this.find('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);
```

Comment: Okay, oops! That's a huge difference. However I am still a bit confused. If I do alert($(this)); as soon as I declare the function I get the alert for other DOM objects (some buttons that submit forms within the same js code that produces the intentional form and input). I am trying to say only ever attach the function to the #leagueLogoUpload form and nothing else, but it is not listening!

Comment: @user3479138 Just realised I've made a mistake before; updated the answer with what it should be.

Comment: Hmm, it's not working. It is alerting me that $this is a totally different object. In this case it is a button that is also generated in the same script as the #leagueLogoUpload form. I must be using $this wrong... does it not reference #leagueLogoUpload form exclusively?

Comment: @user3479138 What's `$this`?

Comment: My understanding is if you attach a function to an element, you can use 'this' to reference the object attached and interact with  the function. So I attach my function to my form element with a specific ID, and try to reference the element within the script with 'this'; but instead it is referencing many other elements (in this case of the 'form' type). The JS file is loaded on startup but I don't want the function run until it is called..

Comment: @user3479138 That makes no sense at all, because you're only calling this function once. Perhaps you should make a fiddle to demonstrate what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I added .attr("id") to the alert and it was in fact the correct form. The real issue lies somewhere else in my code! Thank you for the help.